# Usage of Composition or Virtual Inheritance in cases like Components of a GameObject

Tags: c++, composition, gameobject, virtual-inheritance

So development of games using the Object Oriented Paradigm in C++ generally involves the idea of GameObjects and their Components. 
Now first and foremost, a GameObject would be a list of components like in the following:

```
class GameObject {
    list<Component*> m_components;
    Component* getComponent(component){}
}
```

Now of course, there are many other ways to implement the gameobject in a better and more efficient way, but that's irrelevant because my focus is going to be on the components. The way gameobjects is composed of components is the classic example of composition through the component based architecture as each component represents a behavior for the GameObject.

The components themselves could be composed of multiple "features" or behaviors that may be needed. For instance, we could have a component that relies on multiple other classes with behavior, such as clickables, drag and drop, and other classes.
Taking into account that each sub component does have everything necessary to function, they don't depend on calling their parent class constructor, and that concrete classes would implement a virtual method from one of the parent classes to perform actions as a result of a behavior occurring. I find it that using virtual inheritance in this case seems like a better solution than having another layer of composition. I'd end up with the following:

```
class Component {}

class clickable : virtual Component {
    virtual onClick();
}

class draggable : virtual Component {
    virtual onDrop();
}
```

Each class does what it needs without interfering with the base class. Each would add a functionality that can be inherited. all the concrete classes need to do is override the provided virtual. These can't be purely interfaces because each class has to do it's own stuff. A concrete class would look like:
    class ConcreteComponent : public Component, public Clickable, public Dragable {}

Problems that need a solution:

1- static_casting is disabled, thus i'd be relying on dynamic_cast, and due to their costly nature, I am going to be forced to only call these during instantiation of a component and add pointers as member variables if any cross behavioral stuff is needed. Am I truly confined to this? would the direct attachment to the base component atleast alleviate part of the problem by allowing static casting to any concrete even if they have parent classes that are virtual base classes?

2- Speed-wise, how much worse would the reliance on virtual classes be than a straight forward inheritance implementation.

3- is there an actual viable composition based implementation on this sort of problem instead? isn't heavy reliance on composition a bad code smell especially when it's used on various levels?

Comment: 4- cache misses. Are you sure you want to iterate over a _list_ of _pointers_? Lookup data locality.

Comment: while I mentioned that this is just an example to show that the gameobject holds a list of some kind of components. It could be a set, vector, or any other implementation that could be optimized for a better behavior like getting the components. 
And I am aware of the ECS system, and it's Cache efficiency over the old way of doing things.
My focus here is on how components should be implemented.